# WampServer and Imagemagick, imagick php module not recogized

Tags: php, apache, imagemagick, wampserver, imagick

I'm using **windows 7, 64 bit.** I downloaded imagemagick - tested it by opening cmd and typing "convert" and it responded with a bunch of stuff that shows its working in windows. edit: but php does not recognize it.

Other relevant things:

1. Using php 5.3.13
2. Apache 2.2.22
3. Added windows variable: name - `MAGICK_HOME` value - `c:\imagemagick`

Added what *appears* to be appropriate `php_imagick.dll` into the php ext folder. (Pasting errors below)

*Please let me know if I've supplied enough info for troubleshooting.* This is an important issue for me.

The thing is here, it appears this is a very finicky system to add. But because I'm designing some distributable code, its imperative that I can test the imagemagick functionality on localhost.

---

**Errors from apache error file:**

---

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_imagick.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

---

**Warning**:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_imagick.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

in **Unknown** on line **0**

---

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_imagick_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

---

**Warning**:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_imagick_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

in **Unknown** on line **0**

Comment: Install it manually. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php)

Comment: Looking into it now. If there are any other insights will be happy to hear them as well.

Answer (score 1):

I read that there can be a bug for windows 64 version. Of course I just assumed that that probably won't apply to me...a type of thinking which is responsible for some many random deaths in this world...

**So I installed *32 bit version of Wamp*...and life is good. Imagick/Imagemagick works**